# Can I use an RNE to travel to Brazil, or do I need a visa?

Tags: visas, brazil

I'm Brazilian, and my wife is Chinese; we just got married in China a few days ago.

The problem is, her visa expired just as we got to China for the wedding, and we don't have time to apply for a new one before our flight to Brazil.

Can she use her [RNE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registro_Nacional_de_Estrangeiros) (which is valid) to come to Brazil instead of needing a visa?

Comment: According to Timatic _'Passengers with an ID card issued to residents of Brazil if stay abroad does not exceed 2 years. '_ are exempt from the requirement to have a visa.. It's not clear that that they're referring to an RNE since there appears also to be an RG card